# find equation of a curve that represents the sum of f(x)

Tags: geometry

Given a straight line with equation `f(x)=2x` where `x belongs to {0,1,2,3,4,5}`, 
how do i find `g(x)` (a curve?) which represents the sum over `f(x)`

In plain english if the price of an object doubles every time I purchase it, what will be the total cost if I purchased it 10 times?

Comment: what do you mean with "sum over $f(x)$"?

Comment: I mean for example at `x=10` the sum over `f(x)` should be `f0) + f(1) + ... + f(10)` @Arnaldo

Answer (score 1):

Your plain English question makes much more sense than your attempt to turn it into algebra.

You should be able to guess the pattern here:

```
number purchased        total price
       1                           P
       2                P + 2P =  3P
       3               3P + 4P =  7P
       4               7P + 8P = 15P
      ...
```

Hint. Think about nearby powers of $2$ in the last column.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$g(x) = f(0) + f(1) + f(2) + ... + f(x) \\
= \sum_{n=0}^{x} f(n)$$

Since $f(x) = 2x$, 
$$\\ g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{x} 2n = 2\sum_{n=0}^{x} n \\
=  2\sum_{n=1}^{x} n = 2(1+2+...+x)$$

There is a useful known result:
 $$1+2+...+N= \sum_{n=1}^{N} n = \frac{N(N+1)}{2}$$

So,
$$g(x) =  2\sum_{n=1}^{x} n = 2 \Big(\frac{x(x+1)}{2} \Big) = x(x+1)$$

Thus your cumulative sum function may be written as

$$g(x) = x^2+x$$

Comment: This answers the OP's _algebra_ question correctly, but it does not answer his real question, since he didn't turn that question into algebra correctly.